# SetImageBitMap isnt working in api 23 android java

Tags: java, android, image, upload

im trying to upload a photo from the gallery to my app with bitmap,
in my emulator(api 22) it works,
but for some reason in my phone(api 23) it doesn't work the picture wont show just an empty page.
here is my code if it matters:

```
public class Photoactivity extends Activity {

private static final int SELECTED_PICTURE=1;
ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photoactivity);

    iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImgView);
}
public void btnClick(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, SELECTED_PICTURE);

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECTED_PICTURE:
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgView);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
    case SELECTED_PICTURE:
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }
        break;
```

with this:

```
    case SELECTED_PICTURE:
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            InputStream is=getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is));
        }
        break;
```

Even better, switch to using [an image-loading library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), such as [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), so this I/O can be done on a background thread, so your UI is not frozen while the image is loading.

Answer (score 0):

It does work. But not in the way you do it. 
When you retrieve the image in onActivityResult you use uri to find it's file path, then you decode file. The problem is that requires read external storage permission which in api23 you need to request. But you don't have to!
All you need to do is get Bitmap directly from uri, by parsing stream.
Example from working code (on api23 as well):

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData()));
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

This way you don;t need access to files. So you don;t need permission to read external storage.

Answer (score 0):

```
 image.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
```

Setting the above `layerType` did the magic after 1 week of struggling.